# button bindings only for mouse - not touchpad

Tags: mouse, xbindkeys

Is there a way to setup key bindings that will work only for mouse and not for the touchpad?

I have tried with `xbindkeys` but it works for both which is annoying.

My `.xbindkeysrc` looks like the following:

```
"xdotool keydown ctrl keydown shift key Tab keyup ctrl keyup shift"
   m | m:0x0 + b:6

"xdotool keydown ctrl key Tab keyup ctrl"
   m | m:0x0 + b:7

"xdotool key ctrl+c"
   m:0x0 + b:9

"xdotool key ctrl+v"
   m:0x0 + b:8
```